# Range Validator Fails ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my model `class` property:

```
[Display(Name = "Animation Interval")]
      [Range(500, 5000, ErrorMessage = "Enter number between 500 to 5000")]
        public Nullable<decimal> ANIMATION_INTERVAL { get; set; }
```

this will fail my Model State condition:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _cmsService.AddTile(cms_tile);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Mode = "create" });
                }
```

When i remove the `[Range]` data annotation,its start working fine,what's the problem is with `range` data annotation.?

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you're trying to set a `Range` attribute on a `Nullable` field. You can't restrict something to a `Range` and then allow for it to be `Null` - you'll find a similar issue if you use `Required` and `Nullable`.